# Have To Refresh or Click The Menu Twice to execute AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm coming across a very simple problem that I just can't seem to put together... I am simply reloading a table of images using AJAX so when the user selects an option (in this case a name) it will reload the box of images. So far, it works and it has been working but the only problem is I either need to do a 'hard' refresh or select the same option twice. Otherwise, it really isn't going to work. If anyone has a solution I'll post as much code as I can. Thanks!

jQuery:

```
    $('select.hotelmain').on('change', function (e){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('got here');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/ajax_images.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("ul.image-list").html(html);
        }
    });
    $('p.selectMessage').css('display','none');
    $('.inner-container').css('display','block');
    $('.display').css('height','0px');
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$hotelId = $_SESSION['curHotelId'];
$hotelDir = '../assets/php/upload/'.$hotelId.'/*';
$count = 1;
if ($hotelId) {
    foreach(glob($hotelDir) as $filename=>$hotelvalue){
        echo '<li id="del'.$count.'" class="image-list"><img src="'.$hotelvalue.'" width="50px" height="50px"/><p class="filename">' . basename($hotelvalue) . '</p> <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary image-list" style="width: 18px;margin-top: -25px;border-radius: 100%;-moz-border-radius: 100%;-o-border-radius: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 100%;" id="del'.$count.'" value="Delete"><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-2" style="margin-left:-3px;"></i></a></li>' . "\n" . "<br>";
        $count++;
    }
}else{}
?>
```

Again, anything helps, I just can't seem to get it to do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely everything after $.ajax needs to be inside the callback fn.

Comment: Just a simple check; your Javascript is wrapped in some sort of DOM Content listener, right? ie: $(function() { ...yourstuff... });

Comment: Yes of course, starts off with $(document).ready(function (){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the same option twice because you have .on(change). Since it's the same, it actually doesn't change.

**EDIT:** instead of change, try **live**.

Comment: Haha, although live is now deprecated it managed to work, due to the fact I have an older version because I use datatables. It worked! Just still doesn't work in IE6, 7, or 8. :( I'll figure out a way around it though, but thank you so much! Can't believe it was as stupid as that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting the hotleId from the session instead of the $_POST vars.
When do you set the $_SESSION['curHotelId']?

Comment: It is set when someone selects a hotel, so I have an ajax that resets the SESSION every time someone re-selects a hotel. I am grabbing that properly cause it does update in the code and everything else that uses this function works. This is the only function I cannot get to work.

Comment: Why are you posting the new id to the ajax_images.php file and not using it?  Are you sure the setting of the session var has happened by the time you do the post listed above?

Comment: All I'm doing is updating the directory because in upload/$_SESSION['curHotelId']/ I have multiple different file names according to the id's of the hotels. It is weird system and took quite some time to figure it out but it works with everything else except refreshing this directory.